# Maximum value of $x+y+z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> If $2(x^3+y^3+z^3) = 3(x+y+z)^2$then
>   find the maximum value of $x+y+z$.
>   given that $x,y,z$ are all non negative integers.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure that the statement is correct?

Comment: It is obvious that you should consider only cases $0 \leq x,y,z \leq 1$. So The maximal value is 2.

Comment: how obvious ?i dont understand

Comment: answer. is 12 anyways

Comment: A, sorry. I didn't notice the replacement.

Comment: Nope. Your answer is wrong. Let's take $x=max(x,y,z)$. See that $2(x^3+y^3+z^3)>2x^3$. And also we have $9x^2=(x+x+x)^2>(x+y+z)^3$. So whenever $x>4.5$ we have $2x^3>9x^2$. So we can conclude that maximum of these 3 can be at maximum 4. (Otherwise the left side is greater than the right). But in this case you'll get 12 only when all 3 are 4. However note that $2*3*4^3=6*64>12^2$.

Comment: Taking kolobokish's comment into account whe have $(x+y+z)^2 = 2(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)$ must be an even perfect square less than or equal to $100$ so $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0,4,8,18,32$ or $50$. So $max(x,y,z) \le 3$. To get $x + y+z=10$ with no value greater than then $3$ is impossible.  To get $x + y+z =8$ we need $x,y,z=3,3,2$ and that doesn't work. For $x+y+z=6$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=18$ we have max is $2$ so only $x,y,z=2,2,2$ and that doesn't work.  And for $x+y+z=4$ we have $0+0+2\ne 4$ so max is $1$ and $1+1+1<4$ fails. That max $x,y,z=0$ the maximum value.

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but $(1,1,0)$ satisfy the above equation.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG we may assume $x\geq y\geq z\geq0$. It is easy to see that $(x,y,z)=(1,1,0)$ is a solution. Let's treat $x,y$ as constant and consider both the LHS and RHS as functions of $z$ only. Clearly, the LHS is a cubic polynomial which is monotonously increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and the RHS is a quadratic polynomial which also increases monotonously on $[0,\infty)$. If we plug in $z=1$, we have $\mathrm{LHS}=6$ and $\mathrm{RHS}=9$. If we plug in $z=2$, then $\mathrm{LHS}=20$ and $\mathrm{RHS}=16$, and the LHS has already "outgrowed" the RHS. Indeed this will always happen regardless of the values of $x,y$ you choose, and a similar argument (by treating $y,z$ as constant and $x$ as the variable, for example) shows that increasing $x,y$ from $(1,1,0)$ will only make the LHS "outgrow" the RHS quicker. Hence, $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are the only two possible solutions to satisfy $\mathrm{LHS}\leq\mathrm{RHS}$, and since $(1,1,1)$ doesn't work, the unique solution to the equation is $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: @user376343 Please read the last line of my answer more closely :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Z3 solver](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) does not find an objective value larger than $2$:

```
from z3 import *

X, Y, Z = Ints('X Y Z')

s = Optimize()

s.add(X >= 0, X <= Y, X < 10)
s.add(Y >= 0, Y <= Z, Y < 10)
s.add(Z >= 0, Z < 10)
s.add(2*(X**3+Y**3+Z**3) == (X+Y+Z)**2)

obj = Sum(X+Y+Z)
s.maximize(obj)

print(s.check())
try:
  print(s.model())
except Z3Exception as ex:
  print(ex)
```

I limited the value ranges and imposed an $ X \le Y \le Z$ ordering to get a fast answer.

Result:

```
sat
[Y = 1, Z = 1, X = 0]
```